# Plotly: Write numbers on Choropleth of the US

Tags: python, plotly-python

For a math assignment I'm working on the distribution of the Electoral College of the US and on the distribution of the electors. I solve a LP to redefine this distribution according to nowadays population in each state.

Now I want to plot my results on a map of the US. I used Plotly to do that. Here is my code :

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

locations = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY",
             "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND",
             "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WV", "WA", "WI", "WY"]
colors = [8.0, 3.0, 11.0, 5.0, 61.0, 9.0, 6.0, 3.0, 3.0, 33.0, 17.0, 3.0, 3.0, 20.0, 11.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 3.0,
          10.0, 11.0, 16.0, 9.0, 5.0, 10.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 14.0, 4.0, 31.0, 16.0, 3.0, 19.0, 7.0, 7.0, 20.0, 3.0,
          8.0, 3.0, 11.0, 44.0, 5.0, 3.0, 14.0, 12.0, 3.0, 9.0, 3.0]


fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(locations=locations, locationmode="USA-states", z=colors, colorscale="Reds"))

fig.update_layout(
    geo = dict(
        scope='usa',
        projection=go.layout.geo.Projection(type = 'albers usa')))
fig.show()
```

My problem is that I'm not able to write the number of electors on each state (I know that the color indicate the number of electors but it is a requirement that the number of elector must be written on each state)

Does someone know how I can write the number of electors on each state ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overlay the choropleth map with a scattergeo as in the example below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

locations = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS",
             "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC",
             "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WV", "WA", "WI", "WY"]

electors = [8, 3, 11, 5, 61, 9, 6, 3, 3, 33, 17, 3, 3, 20, 11, 5, 5, 7, 8, 3, 10, 11, 16, 9, 5, 10, 3, 3, 5, 3, 14,
            4, 31, 16, 3, 19, 7, 7, 20, 3, 8, 3, 11, 44, 5, 3, 14, 12, 3, 9, 3]

layout = dict(font=dict(size=8), geo=dict(scope="usa", projection=dict(type="albers usa")))

data = []

data.append(go.Choropleth(locations=locations, z=electors, locationmode="USA-states", colorscale="Reds"))
data.append(go.Scattergeo(locations=locations, text=electors, locationmode="USA-states", mode="text"))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

[image]